# How can I randomly sample the contents of a file?

Tags: perl, file, random, sample

I have a file with contents

```
abc
def
high
lmn
...
...
```

There are more than 2 million lines in the files.
I want to randomly sample lines from the files and output 50K lines.  Any thoughts on how to approach this problem? I was thinking along the lines of Perl and its `rand` function (Or a handy shell command would be neat).

**Related (Possibly Duplicate) Questions:**

- [Randomly Pick Lines From a File Without Slurping It With Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692312/randomly-pick-lines-from-a-file-without-slurping-it-with-unix)
- [How can I get exactly n random lines from a file with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856494/command-to-get-exactly-n-random-lines-from-a-file)

Comment: Is the number of lines you want to output exact or is it OK for the algorithm to output roughly 2.5% of all lines?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you basically want to output about 2.5% of all lines, this would do:

```
print if 0.025 > rand while <$input>;
```

Comment: If the file size varies, you could calculate the percentage by counting the lines (cf. perlfaq5) and dividing that into the number of lines desired.

Comment: This is a really good solution because it avoids the naive approaches to solving this problem, which involve jumping to random points in the file or (even worse!) sorting the input.

Comment: @James Thompson: while it might look like a good solution, it actually is not a correct solution for the question. There is no way to guarantee that it will return 50k rows.

Comment: Mine is a perfectly fine solution if you want to sample roughly 2.5% of all lines. Mine is not the right solution if the requirement is to output exactly 50,000 lines. I explicitly stated the approximate nature of this. For the latter problem, I believe I once read a single-pass algorithm but I cannot remember it now.

Comment: The algorithm that Sinan is thinking of is called the Reservoir Sampling Algorithm. It's covered well on this site  and elsewhere on the Internet.

Answer (score 5):

Shell way:

```
sort -R file | head -n 50000
```

Comment: Which sort is this? Mine (GNU coreutils 5.93) doesn't support -R.

Comment: [sinan@kas ~]$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 7.4
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: => sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 6.10

Answer (score 3):

From [perlfaq5: "How do I select a random line from a file?"](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How_do_I_select_a_ra)

---

Short of loading the file into a database or pre-indexing the lines in the file, there are a couple of things that you can do.

Here's a reservoir-sampling algorithm from the Camel Book:

```
srand;
rand($.) < 1 && ($line = $_) while <>;
```

This has a significant advantage in space over reading the whole file in. You can find a proof of this method in *The Art of Computer Programming*, Volume 2, Section 3.4.2, by Donald E. Knuth.

You can use the File::Random module which provides a function for that algorithm:

```
use File::Random qw/random_line/;
my $line = random_line($filename);
```

Another way is to use the Tie::File module, which treats the entire file as an array. Simply access a random array element.

Comment: Following this answer lead me to a great description of reservoir sampling, and an easy way to extend the Camel Book code from one line to `k` items: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12733515/2016618

Answer (score 2):

If you need to extract an exact number of lines:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Number of lines to pick and file to pick from
# Error checking omitted!
my ($pick, $file) = @ARGV;

open(my $fh, '<', $file)
    or die "Can't read file '$file' [$!]\n";

# count lines in file
my ($lines, $buffer);
while (sysread $fh, $buffer, 4096) {
    $lines += ($buffer =~ tr/\n//);
}

# limit number of lines to pick to number of lines in file
$pick = $lines if $pick > $lines;

# build list of N lines to pick, use a hash to prevent picking the
# same line multiple times
my %picked;
for (1 .. $pick) {
    my $n = int(rand($lines)) + 1;
    redo if $picked{$n}++
}

# loop over file extracting selected lines
seek($fh, 0, 0);
while (<$fh>) {
    print if $picked{$.};
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: Really nice approach. The only thing missing is check if $pick <= $lines - otherwise it will hang on the for() loop.

Comment: Bug:int(rand($lines)) can return a 0 but $. starts at 1.

Comment: @jermdemo: Argh, and `rand` returns a value less than the argument, so it wouldn't pick the last line. Silly 1-based variables... I added a `+1` to fix both edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

Perl way:

use CPAN. There is module [File::RandomLine](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::RandomLine) that does exactly what you need.