# random number with equal probability from a continuous stream

Tags: algorithm, stream

You have a continuous stream of numbers coming in. You don't have space to store them all. But devise a mechanism by which at any point of time you select any number with equal probability.

Comment: Incomplete question. Please be specific with your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732982/design-a-storage-algorithm

Answer (score 7):

Have space for one number, and for the nth number replace it with that number with probability 1/n.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling