# Possible bug in Knuth's pseudo code for Reservoir sampling

Tags: algorithm, random, combinations

Below is the pseodo code from Knuth for Reservoir Sampling (how to select `k` numbers from a set of `n` numbers, making sure that every number has the same probability).

Init: a reservoir with the size：`k`.

```
for i = k+1 to N
    M = random(1, i);

    if (M < k) // should this be if (M <= k)
       SWAP the Mth value and ith value
    end if    
end for
```

From this code,the probability of `M < K` is `(k-1)/i`, not `k/i`, so I think the `if` statement in the body of the loop should be `if (M < =k)`. I tried to test the difference between them, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Can random(1,i) return i?

Comment: @Joni, looking at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling), I think the answer is yes, it _is_ inclusive.

Comment: What is the origin of the actual code? Even if it is based on Knuth, it does not seem to be in MIX, so presumably there has been some translation.

Answer (score 4):

You are right. However, your code does not correctly implement Algorithm R. The bug is yours (or whomever wrote this code), not Knuth's ;-)

Quoting from Knuth (The Art of Computer Programming Vol.2 3Ed 1998, p.144):

> ... A problem arises if we don't know the value of N in advance, since the precise value of N is crucial in Algorithm S. Suppose we want to select n items  at random from a file, without knowing exactly how many are present in that  file. We could first go through and count the records, then take a second pass  to select them; but it is generally better to sample m > n of the original items  on the first pass, where m is much less than N, so that only m items must be considered on the second pass. The trick, of course, is to do this in
>   such a way  that the final result is a truly random sample of the original file.
>
> Since we don't know when the input is going to end, we must keep track of  a random sample of the input records seen so far, thus always being prepared for  the end. As we read the input we will construct a "reservoir" that contains only  the records that have appeared among the previous samples. The first n records  always go into the reservoir. When the (t + 1)st record is being input, for t>n,  we will have in memory a table of n indices pointing to the records that we have  chosen from among the first t. The problem is to maintain this situation with  t increased by one, namely to find a new random sample from among the t + 1  records now known to be present. It is not hard to see that we should include  the new record in the new sample with probability n/(t + 1), and in such a case  it should replace a random element of the previous sample.
>
> Thus, the following procedure does the job:
>
> **Algorithm R** (Reservoir sampling). To select n records at random from a file of  unknown size > n, given n > 0. An auxiliary file called the "reservoir" contains  all records that are candidates for the final sample. The algorithm uses a table  of distinct indices *I*[j] for 1 < j < n, each of which points to one of the records  in the reservoir.
>
> **R1.** [Initialize.] Input the first n records and copy them to the reservoir. Set *I*[j] ← j for 1 < j < n, and set t ← m ← n. (If the file being sampled has fewer than n records, it will of course be necessary to abort the algorithm  and report failure. During this algorithm, indices *I*[1], ..., *I*[n] point to the  records in the current sample; m is the size of the reservoir; and t is the  number of input records dealt with so far.)
>
> **R2.** [End of file?] If there are no more records to be input, go to step R6.
>
> **R3.** [Generate and test.] Increase t by 1, then generate a random integer M between 1 and t (inclusive). If M > n, go to R5.
>
> **R4.** [Add to reservoir.] Copy the next record of the input file to the reservoir, increase m by 1, and set I[M] ← m. (The record previously pointed to by  I[M] is being replaced in the sample by the new record.) Go back to R2.
>
> **R5.** [Skip.] Skip over the next record of the input file (do not include it in the  reservoir), and return to step R2.
>
> **R6.** [Second pass.] Sort the *I* table entries so that *I*[1] < ... < *I*[n]; then go through the reservoir, copying the records with these indices into the output  file that is to hold the final sample.

A pseudocode of Algorithm R would look something like:

```
for j= 1 to n
    Reservoir[j]= File.GetNext()
    I[j]= j

t=n // number of input records so far
m=n // size of the reservoir

while not File.EOF()
    x= File.GetNext()
    t++
    M= Random(1..t)
    if (M<=n)
        m++
        Reservoir[m]= x
        I[M]= m

Sort(I[1..n])

for j= 1 to n
    Output[j]= Reservoir[I[j]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it should be `<=`. This is based on looking at the code in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling), and also working through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12733515/834521), which is an excellent explanation as to why each number in the superset has an equal chance of appearing. I would hesitate to claim that there is a mistake in Knuth, however!

Comment: +1 for assuming that Knuth knows what he's doing and that his work has been widely reviewed.