# Sampling module for Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sampling

Is there a decent Python library for various sampling techniques?

I know of the standard `random` module which does contain useful core functions like `shuffle` and `choice`.  I'm also aware of various libraries that provide sampling from known distributions (like `scipy.stats` and `sympy.stats`).

I'm curious if there exists a library for some of the more sophisticated techniques like reservoir sampling.  Note that reservoir sampling is just an example; I'm looking for a library of many such functions.  An example in the Clojure ecosystem is https://github.com/bigmlcom/sampling.

Comment: Reservoir sampling algo here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612648/reservoir-sampling

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the sampling algorithms have been implemented in separate packages.

For instance, there's a [reservoir-sampling program](https://github.com/RyanBalfanz/reservoir-sampling-cli) (which only provides a client interface). The code is simple enough that you could verify it and grab what you need. Alternatively, you could check out the answer that [@Gerrat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429982/gerrat) [mentioned from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612822/700228).

Numpy's [random](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) can sample from various distributions as well.

Sounds like a good time to unify and make a sampling package or add on to scipy.