# randomly subsampling lines in a file

Tags: python

I have a file like this:

```
Tree 5
Jaguar 9
Cat 23
Monkey 12
Gorilla 67
```

Is possible to randomly subsample 3 of these lines?
For example:

```
Jaguar 9
Gorilla 67
Tree 5
```

or

```
Monkey 12
Tree 5
Cat 23
```

etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) on [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

```
import random

random.sample(open('foo.txt', 'r').readlines(), 3)
```

Comment: Is it the most efficient method? especially if there is a huge amount of data? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Noah16 For huge files, you would probably want [reservoir sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612648/reservoir-sampling).