# Is using np.random bad practice for a single int?

Tags: python, numpy, standards, libraries

Following from a comment on [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64307180/913098) I recently posted,

> Any reason you are using numpy.random instead of the standard random
> module?
>
> @Gulzar "Any reason not to?" - Yes: ModuleNotFoundError: No module
> named 'numpy'. It's bad practice to require an external library for
> something that can be done equally well using the standard library.
> Actually, the standard library would make the program slightly shorter
> (import random; random.randint(low_limit, high_limit + 1)).

I would like to better understand why using `np.random` is so much worse than just the standard random?

Reasons I preferred `np.random` in this case:

1. My code base is based on numpy, never had trouble with it. Can just `pip install` it.
2. It's extremely common.

Is there really something *wrong* with using numpy when one could use the standard? Since when is using external libraries bad practice (with 4 upvotes at the moment of posting this question)?

Examples I see as *worse than the standard*:

1. Slow
2. Unreadable
3. Hard to incorporate into your code

Maybe I should add some items to that list?

I would like to avoid bad practices in the future :)

---

**I hope I made this question specific enough not to be considered opinion based.

Please suggest improvements to the question instead of closing if it still is not specific enough.**

Comment: In that context where `numpy` is not need elsewhere, using `random` would produce faster and more general code.  Especially since you had to take the extra step of `[0]` to extract a scalar value from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `ipython` session with `numpy` already imported:

```
In [1]: import random
In [2]: random.randint(0,100)
Out[2]: 89
In [3]: timeit random.randint(0,100)
1.5 µs ± 2.05 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [4]: timeit np.random.randint(0,100)
5.46 µs ± 121 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [5]: timeit np.random.randint(0,100,1)[0]
23.3 µs ± 1.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything that has to be installed, that the user might not already have, is a cost. As well, `import numpy` can take several seconds (a one-time cost per program run, but it can be very annoying, especially if someone tries to run your program many times in a shell script).

If Numpy is already required for the rest of your program logic, then go ahead. The costs here are all one-time costs; once you are forced to pay them, that's that.