# Select random lines from a file

Tags: bash, shell, random, text-processing

In a Bash script, I want to pick out N random lines from input file and output to another file.

How can this be done?

Comment: Sort the file randomly and pick N first lines.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354659/how-to-select-random-lines-from-a-file.

Comment: this is not a duplicate --  he wants N lines vs 1 line.

Comment: related: [Randomly Pick Lines From a File Without Slurping It With Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/692312/4279)

Comment: I disagree with `sort -R` as it does a lot of excess work, particularly for long files.   You can use `$RANDOM`, `% wc -l`, `jot`, `sed -n` (à la https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022431/563329), and bash functionality (arrays, command redirects, etc) to define your own `peek` function which will actually run on 5,000,000-line files.

Answer (score 838):

Use [`shuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf) with the `-n` option as shown below, to get `N` random lines:

```
shuf -n N input > output
```

Comment: If you just need a random set of lines, not in a random order, then shuf is very inefficient (for big file): better is to do reservoir sampling, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692401/933228).

Comment: I ran this on a 500M row file to extract 1,000 rows and it took 13 min. The file had not been accessed in months, and is on an Amazon EC2 SSD Drive.

Comment: so is this in essence more random that `sort -R` ?

Comment: @MonaJalal nope just faster, since it doesn't have to compare lines at all.

Comment: Does it eventually yield the same line more than once?

Comment: @FrederickNord You might get repeated values when there are repeated lines, but the same line is not yielded twice.

Comment: `shuf file.txt` outputs randomly the lines to standard output. -----
`shuf -r -n 5 file.txt` - The flag `-r` allows the command to yield repeated lines; Don't forget to set the number of lines you want to be printed using the `-n` flag, otherwise it will output forever. ------
`sort -R` will shuffle, but it will also group identical keys. So if you have repeated lines but you don't want repeated values, pipe it with the `uniq` command. e.g. `sort -R file.txt | uniq`

Comment: But this will also reorder the lines.

Comment: with regards to the sort issue just pipe it to sort, extract 1000 lines from 557344 lines took 0,019s)
`$ wc -l list_n_sorted`
557344 list_n_sorted`

`$ time shuf -n 1000 list_n_sorted | sort -n > test_file`

`real 0m0.019s`
`user 0m0.010s`
`sys 0m0.012s`
`

Comment: time shuf -n 1000 500M.txt  -> 0m21.447s in a very mediocre SSD (127MB/s)

Answer (score 197):

Sort the file randomly and pick first `100` lines:

```
lines=100
input_file=/usr/share/dict/words

# This is the basic selection method
<$input_file sort -R | head -n $lines

# If the file has duplicates that must never cause duplicate results
<$input_file sort | uniq        | sort -R | head -n $lines

# If the file has blank lines that must be filtered, use sed
<$input_file sed $'/^[ \t]*$/d' | sort -R | head -n $lines
```

Of course `<$input_file` can be replaced with any piped standard input. This (`sort -R` and `$'...\t...'` to get `sed` to match tab chars) works with GNU/Linux and BSD/macOS.

Comment: `sort` actually sorts identical lines together, so if you may have duplicate lines and you have `shuf` (a gnu tool) installed, it's better to use it for this.

Comment: Andalso, this is definitely going to make you wait **a lot** if you have a considerably huge file -- 80kk lines --, whereas, `shuf -n` acts quite instantaneously.

Comment: sort -R is not available under Mac OS X (10.9)

Comment: @Rubens: why do you think there should be significant time performance difference? `shuf` uses `O(n)`-time while `sort -R` might use `O(n * log n)` algorithm. Even if `n=1000000`; log(n) ~10.

Comment: @tfb785: `sort -R` is probably GNU option, install GNU coreutils. btw, `shuf` is also part of coreutils.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian For two reasons, actually: first, I ran the code, and it takes **much** longer; second, if your file is reasonably large, which was my case, `sort` dives into external memory, sorting chunks of the file, and later merging them. Complexity hides complexity! :D

Comment: @Rubens: `shuf` doesn't work **at all** if the file is so large that it requires external memory. *"I ran the code, and it takes much longer;"* Could you share the code with the corresponding input?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The code: `sort -R input | head -n <num_lines>`. The input file was 279GB, with 2bi+ lines. Can't share it, though. Anyway, the point is you can keep *some* lines in memory with shuffle to do the random selection of what to output. Sort is going to sort the **entire** file, regardless of what your needs are.

Comment: @Rubens in other words, your claim that `sort -R` is slower than `shuf` is *unsubstantiated* because `shuf` tries to load the whole file in memory and it would be difficult for 279GB file.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian True that. `shuf` does indeed load the whole data into memory. Just recalled I actually had to write an `sshuf`, which allows for framed random-picking of lines. This I can [share](http://pastebin.com/Ay1iZBAD). Anyway, `sort -R` itself would take too long to finish, and would still be a needless overhead (in memory or not).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian **Correction**: *`sort -R` itself would take too long to finish, and would still be a needless overhead (in memory or not)* **in case** a framed-shuffle suffices. Other than that, disk would be the bottleneck, and operating in `O(n)` or `O(n log n)` in memory would indeed make no much difference. Framed-shuffles was enough for my needs.

Comment: As everyone said, this approach is only useful when using an small file. For files with more than 1M lines use shuf.

Comment: Doesn't work on mac, since `-R` is not a valid option.

Comment: FWIW shuf for me is able to give random lines from a file much too large to fit all into RAM, and uses only about 1M RAM itself while doing so.  So while I think it might read the entire file, I don't think it reads it into memory all at once. FWIW.  In terms of "why is it slower if it's O(n) vs. O(n*logn)" there are other things at play, shuf doesn't actually compare lines so can run faster.

Comment: Worth noting that `sort` and `head` read from and output into standard output if no input or output files are specified, so one can pipe input into either command.

Answer (score 30):

Well According to a comment on the shuf answer he shuffed 78 000 000 000 lines in under a minute.

Challenge accepted...

EDIT: I beat my own record

### powershuf did it in 0.047 seconds

```
$ time ./powershuf.py -n 10 --file lines_78000000000.txt > /dev/null 
./powershuf.py -n 10 --file lines_78000000000.txt > /dev/null  0.02s user 0.01s system 80% cpu 0.047 total
```

The reason it is so fast, well I don't read the whole file and just move the file pointer 10 times and print the line after the pointer.

[Gitlab Repo](https://gitlab.com/aapjeisbaas/shuf)

#### Old attempt

First I needed a file of 78.000.000.000 lines:

```sh
seq 1 78 | xargs -n 1 -P 16 -I% seq 1 1000 | xargs -n 1 -P 16 -I% echo "" > lines_78000.txt
seq 1 1000 | xargs -n 1 -P 16 -I% cat lines_78000.txt > lines_78000000.txt
seq 1 1000 | xargs -n 1 -P 16 -I% cat lines_78000000.txt > lines_78000000000.txt
```

This gives me a a file with **78 Billion** newlines ;-)

Now for the shuf part:

```
$ time shuf -n 10 lines_78000000000.txt










shuf -n 10 lines_78000000000.txt  2171.20s user 22.17s system 99% cpu 36:35.80 total
```

The bottleneck was CPU and not using multiple threads, it pinned 1 core at 100% the other 15 were not used.

Python is what I regularly use so that's what I'll use to make this faster:

```py
#!/bin/python3
import random
f = open("lines_78000000000.txt", "rt")
count = 0
while 1:
  buffer = f.read(65536)
  if not buffer: break
  count += buffer.count('\n')

for i in range(10):
  f.readline(random.randint(1, count))
```

This got me just under a minute:

```
$ time ./shuf.py         










./shuf.py  42.57s user 16.19s system 98% cpu 59.752 total
```

I did this on a Lenovo X1 extreme 2nd gen with the i9 and Samsung NVMe which gives me plenty read and write speed.

I know it can get faster but I'll leave some room to give others a try.

Line counter [source: Luther Blissett](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch04s07.html)

Comment: Well, according to your description of powershuf's inner functionning, it looks like it is just randomish. Using a file with just two lines, one being 1 character long, the other being 20 characters long, I expect both lines to be choosen with equal chances. This doesn't seem to be the case with your program.

Comment: There was an issue with files shorter than 4KB and some other math mistakes that made it horrible with small files. I fixed them for as far as I could find the issues, please give it another try.

Comment: Hi Stein. It doesn't seem to work. Did you test it the way I suggested in my above comment? Before making something quicker than shuf, I reckon you should focus on making something that works as accurately as shuf. I really doubt anyone can beat shuf with a python program. BTW, unless you use the `-r` option, shuf doesn't output the same line twice, and of course this takes additional processing time.

Comment: Why does powershuf discard the first line? Can it ever pick the very first line? It seems to also funnel the search in a weird way: if you have 10 lines too long, then 1 line of valid length, then 5 lines and another line of valid length, then the iteration will find the 10 lines more often than the 5, and funnel about two thirds of the time into the first valid line. The program doesn't promise this, but it would make sense to me if the lines were effectively filtered by length and then random lines were chosen from that set.

Comment: The question is how to get random lines from a text file in a bash script, not how to write a Python script.

Answer (score 9):

My preferred option is very fast, I sampled a tab-delimited data file with 13 columns, 23.1M rows, 2.0GB uncompressed.

```sh
# randomly sample select 5% of lines in file
# including header row, exclude blank lines, new seed

time \
awk 'BEGIN  {srand()} 
     !/^$/  { if (rand() <= .05 || FNR==1) print > "data-sample.txt"}' data.txt

# awk  tsv004  3.76s user 1.46s system 91% cpu 5.716 total
```

Comment: This is brilliant--and super fast.

Comment: Randomly sample select _approximately_ 5% of lines in file. Law of large numbers will make it close, but since each line is decided independently, there is no way to guarantee it will actually be 5% of lines.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
seq 1 100 | python3 -c 'print(__import__("random").choice(__import__("sys").stdin.readlines()))'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness's sake and because it's available from Arch's community repos: there's also a tool called `shuffle`, but it doesn't have any command line switches to limit the number of lines and warns in its man page: "Since shuffle reads the input into memory, it may fail on very large files."

Answer (score 0):

Here is an "incremental random sampler" that picks exactly N samples from any number of lines in one pass, never storing more than N lines in memory.

- It selects exactly N samples.
- Each line has an equal probability of being chosen.
- It reads through the input just once.
- No sorting, iterating or comparing needed.
- It never stores more than N lines in memory at a time.

It works as follows:

1. Store the first N lines in samples[0..N-1]
2. After N lines, pick a random number r from 0 to (#linesSoFar - 1)
3. If r < N, replace samples[r] with the new line. Otherwise, skip it.
4. After reading all the lines, shuffle samples[] just in case any of the first N lines happen to still be there in their original non-random order.

I did a proof to make sure that this gives each line an equal probability of being included in the final sample. I also did some large empirical experiments to demonstrate the same thing.

I came up with this algorithm when I needed to get a random sample of 10,000 messages from a log with unknown millions of entries over a variable amount of time. Using this approach, I didn't need to store more than N messages at once, nor guess in advance what fraction of the messages to keep in order to end up with the desired N samples.

Here is a python implementation. You can call it from the command line via:

```
`cat <inputFile> | python incremental_sampler.py [#samples=1000] > <outputFile>`
```

or call it from your own python program. It is simple enough that I have found it trivial to port to other languages.

```
import random
import sys


# Incremental random sampler.
#   Author: Randy Wilson, Ph.D.
#   Date: 14 February 2007
# Generates a random sample of all the values passed to it,
#   without ever having to store more than the number of samples
#   being taken ('max_samples').
# Stores the first 'max_samples' values. 
# Then chooses a random index from 0..num_samples-1.
#   If the random index is within the first max_samples, 
#     then that array element is replaced.
#     Otherwise, the new value is ignored.
# This gives every incoming sample the same probability of
#   max_samples/num_samples of being included.
#
# For example, if max_samples=1000, and 50,000 values are 
#   passed to add_sample(), then the first 1000 samples are all kept.
# After that, there is a 1000/1001, 1000/1002, etc., chance
#   of each sample replacing one selected earlier.
# After adding all 50,000 samples, get_samples() will shuffle the 
#   1000 samples that were kept and return them.
# Never were more than 1000 samples stored during the entire process.
# This means you could get a sample from billions of values 
#   without blowing out memory.
class IncrementalSampler:
    def __init__(self, sample_size):
        # Number of samples desired in the end
        self.sample_size = sample_size
        # Number of samples added via add_sample so far
        self.num_samples = 0
        # Values included in the random sample so far. These may be replaced by values added later.
        self.samples = []

    def add_sample(self, value):
        if self.num_samples < self.sample_size:
            self.samples.append(value)
        else:
            position = random.randint(0, self.num_samples)
            if position < self.sample_size:
                self.samples[position] = value
        self.num_samples += 1

    def get_samples(self):
        random.shuffle(self.samples)
        return self.samples


# Command-line interface.
# Usage: cat <file> | incremental_sampler.py [#samples] > <outputFile>
sample_size = 1000
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    sample_size = int(sys.argv[1])
sampler = IncrementalSampler(sample_size)
for line in sys.stdin:
    sampler.add_sample(line.rstrip('\r\n'))
for line in sampler.get_samples():
    print(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# Function to sample N lines randomly from a file
# Parameter $1: Name of the original file
# Parameter $2: N lines to be sampled 
rand_line_sampler() {
    N_t=$(awk '{print $1}' $1 | wc -l) # Number of total lines

    N_t_m_d=$(( $N_t - $2 - 1 )) # Number oftotal lines minus desired number of lines

    N_d_m_1=$(( $2 - 1)) # Number of desired lines minus 1

    # vector to have the 0 (fail) with size of N_t_m_d 
    echo '0' > vector_0.temp
    for i in $(seq 1 1 $N_t_m_d); do
            echo "0" >> vector_0.temp
    done

    # vector to have the 1 (success) with size of desired number of lines
    echo '1' > vector_1.temp
    for i in $(seq 1 1 $N_d_m_1); do
            echo "1" >> vector_1.temp
    done

    cat vector_1.temp vector_0.temp | shuf > rand_vector.temp

    paste -d" " rand_vector.temp $1 |
    awk '$1 != 0 {$1=""; print}' |
    sed 's/^ *//' > sampled_file.txt # file with the sampled lines

    rm vector_0.temp vector_1.temp rand_vector.temp
}

rand_line_sampler "parameter_1" "parameter_2"
```

Answer (score -2):

In the below 'c' is the number of lines to select from the input. Modify as needed:

```
#!/bin/sh

gawk '
BEGIN   { srand(); c = 5 }
c/NR >= rand() { lines[x++ % c] = $0 }
END { for (i in lines)  print lines[i] }

' "$@"
```

Comment: This does not guarantee that eactly `c` lines are selected. At best you can say that the average number of lines being selected is `c`.

Comment: That is incorrect: c/NR will be >= 1 (larger than any possible value of rand() ) for the first c lines, thus filling lines[].  x++ % c forces lines[] to c entries, assuming there are at least c lines in the input

Comment: Right, `c/NR` will be **guaranteed** to be larger than any value produced from `rand` for the **first c lines**. **After** that, it may or may not be larger than `rand`.  Therefore we can say that `lines` in the end contains **at least** c entries, and in general more than that, i.e. **not** exactly c entries. Furthermore, the first c lines of the file are always picked, so the whole selection is not what could be called a **random** pick.

Comment: uh, x++ % c constrains lines[] to indices 0 to c-1. Of course, the first c inputs initially fill lines[], which are replaced in round robin fashion when the random condition is met. A small change (left as an exercise for the reader) could be made to randomly replace entries in lines[], rather than in a round-robin.