# How to select random lines from a file

Tags: linux, bash, text, random, sed

I have a text file containing 10 hundreds of lines, with different lengths. Now I want to select N lines randomly, save them in another file, and remove them from the original file.
I've found some answers to this question, but most of them use a simple idea: sort the file and select first or last N lines. unfortunately this idea doesn't work to me, because I want to preserve the order of lines.
I tried this piece of code, but it's very slow and takes hours.

```
FILEsrc=$1;
FILEtrg=$2;
MaxLines=$3;
let LineIndex=1;
while [ "$LineIndex" -le "$MaxLines" ]
do
# count number of lines
NUM=$(wc -l $FILEsrc | sed 's/[ \r\t].*$//g');
let X=(${RANDOM} % ${NUM} + 1);
echo $X;
sed -n ${X}p ${FILEsrc}>>$FILEtrg; #write selected line into target file
sed -i -e  ${X}d ${FILEsrc};       #remove selected line from source file
LineIndex=`expr $LineIndex + 1`;
done
```

I found this line the most time consuming one in the code:

```
sed -i -e  ${X}d ${FILEsrc};
```

is there any way to overcome this problem and make the code faster?
Since I'm in hurry, may I ask you to send me complete c/c++ code for doing this?

Comment: This could be done very fast in a real programming languages instead of just a shell.

Comment: "Fast ways" include reading the appropriate contents into memory, manipulating, and writing-once or reading the line offsets, performing delta calculations, and writing once .. both are much simpler in other environments and both take advantage of writing once.

Comment: @dystroy: Define "real programming language".

Comment: @phresnel any language complete enough so that you may use the standard API instead of looking for hacks and for the options of all the utilities (sed, awk, etc.) you may have on your computer. Both approach work but one does it in predictable development and execution times. Don't take it wrong : I'm interested in the ingenious way to do it on shell, but I just say it may be easier and more effective to type 30 lines of a programming language.

Comment: @dystroy That's somewhat of a silly argument -- sed, awk, and other tools used in such a fashion can themselves be viewed as an API insofar as there is a defined exposed interface (and "standard" for many Linux distributions). And APIs can be specified as requirements .. of course I agree that it would likely be *easier* to use perl or ruby or python (all of which are programs that one "may have on [their] computer").

Comment: I suppose my immediate jump to recommending another environment is that I do know how to [effectively] use arrays in Bash, which are a fairly vital concept in solving problems like this and are used [in some fashion] in all the answers posted. I found [this tutorial on bash arrays](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/). YMMV.

Comment: @dystroy: POSIX _is_ an API (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), sed and awk are part of that API (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). Your definition does not convince me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select random lines from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245638/select-random-lines-from-a-file)

Answer (score 6):

A simple O(n) algorithm is described in:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling

```
array R[k];    // result
integer i, j;

// fill the reservoir array
for each i in 1 to k do
    R[i] := S[i]
done;

// replace elements with gradually decreasing probability
for each i in k+1 to length(S) do
    j := random(1, i);   // important: inclusive range
    if j <= k then
        R[j] := S[i]
    fi
done
```

Comment: here's the same [Algorithm R in Python (`reservoir_sample()` function)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32792504/4279)

Answer (score 3):

Generate all your offsets, then make a single pass through the file. Assuming you have the desired number of offsets in `offsets` (one number per line) you can generate a single `sed` script like this:

```
sed "s!.*!&{w $FILEtrg\nd;}!" offsets
```

The output is a `sed` script which you can save to a temporary file, or (if your `sed` dialect supports it) pipe to a second `sed` instance:

```
... | sed -i -f - "$FILEsrc"
```

Generating the `offsets` file left as an exercise.

Given that you have the Linux tag, this should work right off the bat. The default `sed` on some other platforms may not understand `\n` and/or accept `-f -` to read the script from standard input.

Here is a complete script, updated to use `shuf` (thanks @Thor!) to avoid possible duplicate random numbers.

```
#!/bin/sh

FILEsrc=$1
FILEtrg=$2
MaxLines=$3

# Add a line number to each input line
nl -ba "$FILEsrc" | 
# Rearrange lines
shuf |
# Pick out the line number from the first $MaxLines ones into sed script
sed "1,${MaxLines}s!^ *\([1-9][0-9]*\).*!\1{w $FILEtrg\nd;}!;t;D;q" |
# Run the generated sed script on the original input file
sed -i -f - "$FILEsrc"
```

Comment: Since I'm in hurry, may I ask you to send me complete c/c++ code for doing this?

Comment: Are you joking?  The source for `sed` is available at http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/sed

Comment: I meant the c++ implementation of the code which does what I want, not source code of sed...!!!

Comment: @Hakim first: Try formulate your question more precisely. Do you want BASH or C/C++ solution? Here are many ways to do this, eg. with bash, perl, python, c, c++ (substitute any language) - so: what you want?!? Second: stackoverflow is __not the your personal programming service__! So, if you in hurry - hire a paid programmer.

Answer (score 3):

[I've updated each solution to remove selected lines from the input, but I'm not positive the `awk` is correct. I'm partial to the `bash` solution myself, so I'm not going to spend any time debugging it. Feel free to edit any mistakes.]

Here's a simple `awk` script (the probabilities are simpler to manage with floating point numbers, which don't mix well with `bash`):

```
tmp=$(mktemp /tmp/XXXXXXXX)
awk -v total=$(wc -l < "$FILEsrc") -v maxLines=$MaxLines '
    BEGIN { srand(); }
    maxLines==0 { exit; }
    { if (rand() < maxLines/total--) {
        print; maxLines--;
      } else {
        print $0 > /dev/fd/3
      }
    }' "$FILEsrc" > "$FILEtrg" 3> $tmp
mv $tmp "$FILEsrc"
```

As you print a line to the output, you decrement `maxLines` to decrease the probability of choosing further lines. But as you consume the input, you decrease `total` to increase the probability. In the extreme, the probability hits zero when `maxLines` does, so you can stop processing the input. In the other extreme, the probability hits 1 once `total` is less than or equal to `maxLines`, and you'll be accepting all further lines.

---

Here's the same algorithm, implemented in (almost) pure `bash` using integer arithmetic:

```
FILEsrc=$1
FILEtrg=$2
MaxLines=$3

tmp=$(mktemp /tmp/XXXXXXXX)

total=$(wc -l < "$FILEsrc")
while read -r line && (( MaxLines > 0 )); do
    (( MaxLines * 32768 > RANDOM * total-- )) || { printf >&3 "$line\n"; continue; }
    (( MaxLines-- ))
    printf "$line\n"
done < "$FILEsrc" > "$FILEtrg" 3> $tmp
mv $tmp "$FILEsrc"
```

Comment: You're still left with the task of removing the selected lines from the source file. If they are all unique, it's a simple `fgrep -vxf "$FILEtrg" "$FILEsrc"`, or you could inline into the script.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete Go program :

```go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    N := 10
    rand.Seed( time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    f, err := os.Open(os.Args[1]) // open the file
    if err!=nil { // and tell the user if the file wasn't found or readable
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    r := bufio.NewReader(f)
    var lines []string // this will contain all the lines of the file
    for {
        if line, err := r.ReadString('\n'); err == nil {
            lines = append(lines, line)
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    nums := make([]int, N) // creates the array of desired line indexes
    for i, _ := range nums { // fills the array with random numbers (lower than the number of lines)
        nums[i] = rand.Intn(len(lines))
    }
    sort.Ints(nums) // sorts this array
    for _, n := range nums { // let's print the line
        fmt.Println(lines[n])
    }
}
```

Provided you put the go file in a directory named `randomlines` in your `GOPATH`, you may build it like this :

```
go build randomlines
```

And then call it like this :

```
  ./randomlines "path_to_my_file"
```

This will print N (here 10) random lines in your files, but without changing the order. Of course it's near instantaneous even with big files.

Comment: Can you tell more about what algorithm you used? Especially for readers not familiar with go?

Comment: +1 not because I favor this approach, but to counter the inexplicable downvote. Voter, please explain?

Comment: It just extract the lines, builds an array of integers between 0 and the lines number, sorts it, and uses this array to print the lines. The point of avoiding looking for shell hacks is that you may easily change it as you wish. Your favorite language would do it as easily (java, python, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting two-pass option with coreutils, sed and awk:

```
n=5
total=$(wc -l < infile)

seq 1 $total | shuf | head -n $n                                           \
| sed 's/^/NR == /; $! s/$/ ||/'                                           \
| tr '\n' ' '                                                              \
| sed 's/.*/   &  { print >> "rndlines" }\n!( &) { print >> "leftover" }/' \
| awk -f - infile
```

A list of random numbers are passed to sed which generates an awk script. If awk were removed from the pipeline above, this would be the output:

```
{ if(NR == 14 || NR == 1 || NR == 11 || NR == 20 || NR == 21 ) print > "rndlines"; else print > "leftover" }
```

So the random lines are saved in `rndlines` and the rest in `leftover`.

Comment: +1 for the `seq | shuf` trick. Wouldn't it make sense to use `head` rather than `tail`, though?

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned "10 hundreds" lines should sort quite quickly, so this is a nice case for the Decorate, Sort, Undecorate pattern. It actually creates two new files, removing lines from the original one can be simulated by renaming.

Note: head and tail cannot be used instead of awk, because they close the file descriptor after given number of lines, making tee exit thus causing missing data in the .rest file.

```
FILE=input.txt
SAMPLE=10
SEP=$'\t'

<$FILE nl -s $"SEP" -nln -w1 | 
  sort -R |
  tee \
    >(awk "NR >  $SAMPLE" | sort -t"$SEP" -k1n,1 | cut -d"$SEP" -f2- > $FILE.rest) \
    >(awk "NR <= $SAMPLE" | sort -t"$SEP" -k1n,1 | cut -d"$SEP" -f2- > $FILE.sample) \
>/dev/null

# check the results
wc -l $FILE*

# 'remove' the lines, if needed
mv $FILE.rest $FILE
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you (GNU sed, sort and seq):

```
n=10
seq 1 $(sed '$=;d' input_file) |
sort -R |
sed $nq | 
sed 's/.*/&{w output_file\nd}/' | 
sed -i -f - input_file
```

Where `$n` is the number of lines to extract.