# Batch Randomize Playlist Containing Percent Symbols

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code (source identified) which is great, but it fails when a title contains a percent symbol. I like the fact that it doesn't use temp files and allows me to overwrite the original file. Any thoughts on how to fix this for percent symbols?

```
  REM Randomize the Onesies playlist
  REM Source: stackoverflow.com/questions/19393155
  REM DOES NOT PROPERLY CREATE PLAYLIST ENTRY FOR ALBUMS CONTAINING PERCENT SYMBOLS (but it's fast)

  for /f "delims=" %%a in (G:\Playlists\Onesies.m3u8) do call set "$$%%random%%=%%a"
  (for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('set $$') do echo(%%b)>G:\Playlists\Onesies.m3u8
  echo Playlist Onesies.m3u8 has been created in the folder G:\Playlists\
  echo.
  pause
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomly rearrange lines in a text file using a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19393155)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problematic part is `call set "$$%%random%%=%%a"`. To explain why, let us start from the beginning.

Simply using `set "$$%random%=%%a"` would not work, because `%random%` would be expanded (read) when the entire `for /F` loop, or more generally spoken, the whole block of code, is parsed, so the same value would be returned for every loop iteration. The `call` trick, toghether with doubled percent signs around variables, introduces another parsing phase, so when the entire `for /F` loop is parsed, `call set "$$%%random%%=%%a"` is interpreted as `call set "$$%random%=%a"`, because each `%%` in a batch file is interpreted as one literal `%`. Hence the `random` variable is not yet expanded.

For every loop iteration, the `for /F` variable becomes replaced by the current iteration value. `call` initiates another parsing phase as already mentioned, so `%random%` becomes replaced by a individual random number per loop iteration. Assuming that `%a` is `abritrary string`, the line is interpreted as `call set "$$%random%=arbitrary string"` first, and after the second parsing phase it becomes `set "$$16384=arbitrary string"`, supposing `%random%` returns the number `16384`.

Now let us take another example value for `%a` which contains a percent sign, like `string with % sign`: after the first parsing phase, we have `call set "$$%random%=string with % sign"`; after the second one, we get something like `set "$$32767=string with  sign"`. The percent sign disappears here, because the command line interpreter encounters a single `%` sign that cannot be paired with another one (where a variable name is expected in between them, like `%random%`), so it simply dismisses that character. In case `%a` contained two `%` signs, for instance, `more % signs % here`, the result would be `more  here` (most likely), because <kbd>SPACE</kbd>`signs`<kbd>SPACE</kbd>, being in between a pair of `%` signs, would be treated as the name of a (undefined, hence empty) variable.

To solve that issue, we need to avoid `%a` to be passed through a second parsing phase. This can be achieved by avoiding `%%a` to appear in the `call` command line.

---

So to overcome the loss of `%` signs in your script, you need to store `%%a` into an interim variable and to do the same double-`%` expansion within the `call` command line like you already do for `random`:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set /A "index=0"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("G:\Playlists\Onesies.m3u8") do (
    set "item=%%a"
    call set "$$%%random%%.%%index%%=%%item%%"
    set /A "index+=1"
)
> "G:\Playlists\Onesies.m3u8" (
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('set $$') do echo(%%b
)
echo Playlist "Onesies.m3u8" has been created in the folder "G:\Playlists\".
echo/

endlocal
pause
```

---

An alternative method is to apply [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Toggling delayed expansion in the loop is necessary to not lose exclamation marks.
set /A "index=0"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("G:\Playlists\Onesies.m3u8") do (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // This loop passes `random` over the `endlocal` barrier:
    for /f %%b in ("!random!.!index!") do (
        endlocal
        set "$$%%b=%%a"
    )
    set /A "index+=1"
)
> "G:\Playlists\Onesies.m3u8" (
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('set $$') do echo(%%b
)
echo Playlist "Onesies.m3u8" has been created in the folder "G:\Playlists\".
echo/

endlocal
pause
```

---

The original code from the question relies on the built-in random number variable `random` which may return duplicate values. This leads to the problem that some lines of the read file get lost.

To resolve this issue, both of the above approaches herein feature a counter called `index` which is of course unique for every single line that is read by the `for /F` loop. This counter value is appended to the random value so that the total concatenated string is unique. Therefore, none of the lines of the read file are lost any more, opposed to the original script.

Comment: Thanks but your code doesn't work. It gives a single line of output (the last line of the text file). I tried several similar approaches and it seems as though the call statement was crucial for getting a full set of output.

Comment: Sorry, I was answering too quick! The code is fixed now. Note that `random` might return duplicate values (also for the original code you posted in your question), leading to lost lines from the original input file; as soon as I find a solution, I will fix that as well.

Comment: Yes you're right. Good catch. I didn't notice the original was losing lines due to duplicate values. And yes your code now works for percent symbols. I look forward to your even better fix!

Comment: I just [fixed the scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39006130/5) so that duplicate `random` value do no longer cause lines to be lost. Take also a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39008715) to the question I linked [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005490/batch-randomize-playlist-containing-percent-symbols/39006130#comment65369147_39005490)...

Comment: Works great. Thanks. Quite a clever answer.

Comment: I had a chance to look at this closer. It works great but I'm curious as to why     set "item=%%a"
    call set "$$%%random%%.%%index%%=%%item%%" preserves the percent symbols? call set "$$%%random%%.%%index%%=%%a" doesn't work.

Comment: [This great post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133) perfectly explains why your method failed. I will update my answer and include an explanation...

Comment: I get it. Thanks. Clears up a long standing mystery for me. Great post.