# How can I count number of lines of actual comments?

Tags: matlab, comments, text-files, counting, software-quality

I have a bunch of MATLAB script/function files that I and the rest of my team need to work on. We have little to no idea what most of the files do, and little to no idea which ones belong together and which ones are separate. We do know we have a total of 36,000 lines. I'd like to know how many of those lines are comments.

Easy, right? Just count how many of them start with the comment start character %.

Well, no. I don't want to count blocks of code that have been commented out as "comments", since they don't actually tell me anything. And I'd prefer not to count "empty" lines used to make one comment line a "headline"

```
% %%%%%%%%
% headline
% %%%%%%%%
```

like so.

So how can I get a sensible estimate of how many lines of **actual informative comments** I have? Is there an easy way to **distinguish natural language** (possibly containing code snippets) from **pure code**?

---

Yes, I know code should be self-explanatory as far as is practical, but the code we have inherited clearly is not. Yes, I know we should probably refactor this mess. The purpose of figuring out how much comments we have is to highlight the technical debt we have here, so that we can allocate resources to this refactoring.

Comment: I assume you can always catch everything starting with % and regexp to catch the ones that are made by something else than just % characters.

Comment: What about comment blocks (`%{ .... %}`)?

Comment: You need to clearly define which lines or combinations you want to exclude, what if I wrote `% ===` or `% % % % %` or `% ------- %`, vs useful section defining comments like `%% Heading`? It's unclear from this description which sort of comments you *are* interested in.

Comment: Catching comments is easy, and catching somewhat obvious special cases like the examples from @Wolfie is also fairly easy. What I'm asking about is sensible heuristics / regexes for seeing the difference between `% useful text`  and `% for i = length(variable):size(gizmos)`. Fortunately, @Dev-iL , the code does not appear to have block comments of that type.

Comment: You can use my solution to get which lines are _technically_ code and which are _technically_ comments, and maybe collect all of those in some log file, but determining how many of these are "real" comments will be a difficult task, possibly involving some machine learning, which is probably out of scope for a single SO question.

Comment: @gibson that last thing, accept that you wont be able to achieve it automatically. it requires not only human level of understanding, but a human expert on MATLAB level of analysis capability.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the semi-documented `mtree` utility for this.

Let's take for example the `.m` file that contains the definition of the `mtree` class itself.

`dbtype mtree` yields (this is just the beginning):

```
1     classdef mtree
2     %MTREE  Create and manipulate M parse trees
3     %   This is an experimental program whose behavior and interface is likely
4     %   to change in the future.
5     
6     % Copyright 2006-2016 The MathWorks, Inc.
7     
8         properties (SetAccess='protected', GetAccess='protected', Hidden)
9             T    % parse tree array
```

Now, if we invoke the `mtree` utility on itself and show the result as text,

```
tree = mtree('mtree.m','-file');
tree.dumptree()
```

here's what we get (again, just the beginning):

```
  1  *:  CLASSDEF:   1/01 
  3     *Cexpr:  ID:   1/10  (mtree)
  4     *Body:  PROPERTIES:   8/05 
  5        *Attr:  ATTRIBUTES:   8/16 
  6           *Arg:  ATTR:   8/26 
  7              *Left:  ID:   8/17  (SetAccess)
  8              *Right:  CHARVECTOR:   8/27  ('protected')
  9           >Next:  ATTR:   8/49 
 10              *Left:  ID:   8/40  (GetAccess)
 11              *Right:  CHARVECTOR:   8/50  ('protected')
 12           >Next:  ATTR:   8/63 
 13              *Left:  ID:   8/63  (Hidden)
 14        *Body:  EQUALS:   9/09
```

As you can see from the above, comment and empty lines (2-7) do not appear on the left side of  the "fractions" in the output.. So if we find a way to get the "numerators", we'll get the numbers of the lines that contain actual code.

We're in luck, since there exists a method that gives us these numerators - `lineno`! So if we call it and apply `unique` to the output, we'll get exactly one copy of each line:

```
uLines = unique(tree.lineno);
nCodeLines = numel(uLines);
```

This yields a value of `269` for `nCodeLines` in R2018b. If you're willing to assume that the last line in a file is always a line of code (and not a comment or a blank), you can just subtract `nCodeLines` from the last element of `uLines` to get the amount of comment lines (`121` in this case). Otherwise, use some other technique to count the total number of lines ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12176519/3372061)).

All that's left is to write this as a function and feed the folder of `.m` files to it :)

Comment: I think this solves the wrong problem. I can already count the number of lines that are not comments. I want to count, among the commented lines, which ones are informative text and which ones are code preceded by a %. Perhaps I could use this method on the lines that start with %, if I strip away the first character....

Comment: @gibson Interesting idea. In any case, what you have is not so much a "counting" problem, but a "recognizing" problem (_counting_ is trivial once you know _what_ to count). I would advise you to pull out all comment lines, then manually go over the first few hundreds and see how many of them are "real" comments and how many are commented-out code - in order to establish some measure of "density of quality comments". Then, multiply by the amount of comment lines. Since all you wanted is an _estimate_, the more lines you include in your density estimate, the more accurate will the end result be.

Comment: I have looked at the first couple of hundred lines of comments, but those were all code with a % in front. But I have also seen at least one file with only "proper" comments. I should probably randomize their order, so I can get a useful estimate from maybe 100 lines.

Comment: (and as a follow up to my idea of using the mtree approach on the commented lines: mtree does not seem to distinguish between lines that are executable and lines that have errors, so `% the for loop is a = 1:length(gizmos) instead of :length(widgets) because bla bla` would count as "code" after the % is stripped)

Comment: There's likely a smarter way to analyze the `mtree`, which could solve this issue, but I'm not familiar with `mtree` enough to comment further.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get comments that aren't just to separate stuff by excluding everything that doesn't contain any text: a-z or A-Z. So, %a is "informative comment", while %----- isn't.

Now, to filter out code, I believe the best way would be to consider `%text text` as a comment and the rest as code: comment is where there is a space between two pieces of text. Piece of text could be anything that contains a letter, or it might be restricted to stuff that are just letters and punctuation (in one case `a=5` is a single piece of text, in the other it is a single piece of not text), and you should exclude reserved code words as well.

This obviously isn't going to work all the time as text having just a single word comment is also an informative comment, say you might have a comment saying `%randomize`. However, consider this: `randomize` could be a comment telling the stuff below does randomization (most likely), or it might be a function that does randomization without taking any parameters and giving any output (say by abusing reflection to actually do something). There is no way to parse between these two options - parser would have to run the code line by line and try whether the line does any work or produces an error to work in such scenarios.

Note that code won't work directly and isn't optimal either, but fixing it should be easy enough.

```
isC = parseComment(commentText)
splitText = split(commentText, ' '); % split by whitespace.
isValidText = false(length(splitText),1);
if (length(isValidText) == 1)
   isC = false;
   return
end
for i=1:length(splitText)
   % find if this "word" is valid non-code text.
   if (contains(splitText(i), [a-z])) % Fix this condition, should suitably check if the thingy is a word in a way you want it.
      if ~isReservedCodeWord(splitText(i)) % here you should exclude if, for, while and so on.
         isValidText(i) = true;
      end
   end
end
%checking of parts is complete, check if the string has 2 adjacent "valid text" parts.
isC = any(isValidText(1:end-1) & isValidText(2:end));
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, since I ended up going in a different direction than either of the answers.

---

I needed an estimate, not necessarily an exact number. I would have been fine with an automated system even if it did misclassify some lines. But I couldn't find a simple enough way to distinguish code from text, so I went with a more manual route.

I just `grep`ed all comment lines, and then scrambled the line order of the output, so that I could look at the last 50 or so lines on my screen, and manually count the ratio of useful comments to commented code. This gives me a rough estimate, and multplying that with the number of lines of comments gives me an estimate of the number of useful lines of comments.

The conclusion is that we have about 36000 lines of almost entirely undocumented code to play with. Yay.

To scramble the line order, I used a `shuffle.bat` file that I found here [How to randomly rearrange lines in a text file using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393155/how-to-randomly-rearrange-lines-in-a-text-file-using-a-batch-file)

So I ended up with `type *.m | grep % | shuffle.bat`

And that was good enough for me.

---

The suggestion by Dev-il to use `mtree` would have been super useful if `mtree` could be made to output the number of lines of parseable, runnable, code. Then I could have `grep` ed out the comment lines, stripped the `%` at the start, and then used `mtree` to count what is runnable code and what is most likely text. Unfortunately, `mtree` will parse anything, and doesn't really distinguish between stuff that ends up making sense as code and stuff that doesn't.