# How to create filelist from folder but with randomised order? In batch

Tags: batch-file

How to create filelist from folder but with randomised order? In batch. Is it possible in batch?

Comment: Could you please expand on the purpose so that we can suggest the most suitable method?

Comment: If you don't need a unique order for every launch you could use `dir` with sorting by size or date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomly rearrange lines in a text file using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393155/how-to-randomly-rearrange-lines-in-a-text-file-using-a-batch-file)

Comment: `Powershell -Nop -C "Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -File | Sort-Object { Get-Random }"`

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion...

First, create a filelist that isn't random.

Then try this:
[How to randomly rearrange lines in a text file using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393155/how-to-randomly-rearrange-lines-in-a-text-file-using-a-batch-file)

If you need help creating the file list to begin with, let me know.