# Import select rows from a csv file R

Tags: r, csv, sqldf

I am using the following code to import data into my program by SimulationID.

```
    args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
    j <- args[1]
    library(sqldf)
    
    select <- paste0("select * from file where SimulID=",j,"")
    data_sim3 <- read.csv.sql("data_sim3.csv", select)

    closeAllConnections()
```

The problem is that sometimes the import will fail:

> Error in connection_import_file(conn@ptr, name, value, sep, eol, skip)
> :    RS_sqlite_import: disk I/O error Calls: read.csv.sql ...
> dbWriteTable -> dbWriteTable -> .local -> connection_import_file
> Error: no such savepoint: dbWriteTable_45140_xkusezrrcf Execution
> halted

Is there a workaround to this problem? Or maybe there is another package. I looked into `data.table` which can import based on row number but would prefer to import based on value of column, SimulID. (Also, the file does not have to be saved as a csv, text will also work).

This is a reference: [Select specified rows when importing CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527587/select-specified-rows-when-importing-csv)

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your error. It may be something in the structure of your `data_sim3.csv` file. How large is this file? Is there something that requires you to use sqldf? If not, why not just `data.table::fread(data_sim3.csv)[SimulID == j]`

Comment: That worked. Thanks! (It's around 4GB.)