# Read csv file with selected rows using data.table's fread

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I was going through some earlier post-

[Quickest way to read a subset of rows of a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243977/quickest-way-to-read-a-subset-of-rows-of-a-csv)

One way to select subset of data is

```
write.csv(iris,"iris.csv")

fread("shuf -n 5 iris.csv")
```

However I was wondering if I can pass some `SQL` query instead of top 5 rows e.g. only import those rows that have `V6 = versicolor`

Is there any way to do this using `fread` function?

Comment: Is it impossible to filter after reading in?

Comment: Have a look at `read.csv.sql()` from `sqldf`

Comment: @ANG - I am aware of read.csv.sql() function. But as I asked clearly in the post, my question was if there is any functionality similar to this in fread()

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in windows (unix alternative is `grep`)

```
write.csv(iris,"iris.csv")

fread(cmd = paste('findstr', 'versicolor', 'iris.csv'))

    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5         V6
 1:  51 7.0 3.2 4.7 1.4 versicolor
 2:  52 6.4 3.2 4.5 1.5 versicolor
 3:  53 6.9 3.1 4.9 1.5 versicolor
 4:  54 5.5 2.3 4.0 1.3 versicolor
 5:  55 6.5 2.8 4.6 1.5 versicolor
 6:  56 5.7 2.8 4.5 1.3 versicolor
 7:  57 6.3 3.3 4.7 1.6 versicolor
 8:  58 4.9 2.4 3.3 1.0 versicolor
 9:  59 6.6 2.9 4.6 1.3 versicolor
10:  60 5.2 2.7 3.9 1.4 versicolor
11:  61 5.0 2.0 3.5 1.0 versicolor
```

It outputs only those rows that contain "versicolor" in any field.

Comment: In macOS, I am getting error as > fread(grep = paste('findstr', 'versicolor', 'iris.csv'))
Error in fread(grep = paste("findstr", "versicolor", "iris.csv")) : 
  unused argument (grep = paste("findstr", "versicolor", "iris.csv"))

Comment: No, you have to replace `findstr` with `grep`.

Comment: Thanks. It works for my problem. But still, it would be a better idea if I could pass some SQL like query to fetch data with a complex relationship

Comment: Well then the answer is no. You can't pass an SQL query to fread.