# Numbering items in word list & reading from lists

Tags: bash, scripting, word-list

I'm writing as script in bash with the purpose of creating characters for purpose of role-playing, and writing. How to i have my script read and randomly select first names from my list (of over 1,000 names)? Also, is there a way that i need to number each entry so that bash will randomly select one word?
(Each word is already in its own line.)

***Ps: Please just tell me if I'm posting this question on the wrong Stack Exchange site.***

Comment: I think you're posting a duplicate question of many that have already been asked... did you try searching?

Comment: @I'L'I I did try searching. If this is a duplicate question, would you please link me to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
shuf -n3 names.txt
```

(selects 3 random names from `names.txt`)

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15065490)

Comment: Thank you, i will notify you of my result when the script is finished.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome :) also, here's a better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15065490