# How to randomly sample lines, output them in a new file, and delete them from the original file?

Tags: bash, file, random

I would like to select at random N lines from a big file called `input_file` (6250000 lines,N=1250000), output the N lines in a new file called `output_file`, and delete the N lines from the original file `input_file`.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245638/select-random-lines-from-a-file-in-bash) post, the first two tasks can be achieved with :

```
sort -R input_file | head -n $N > output_file
```

How to delete the selected N lines from `input_file` ?

Answer (score 0):

This does the job if we don't care about the ordering of the lines after deleting the N lines:

```
# shuffle the input file
sort -R input_file > shuffled
# select N lines
head -n $N shuffled > output_file
# delete the selected N lines
sed -i -e '1,<N>d' shuffled
```

`shuffled` now contains lines in `input_file` that are not in `output_file`.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting `N` random lines is easy:

```
# select N random lines
sort -R input_file | head -n $N > output_file
```

If all lines in the input are unique, then you can remove the selected lines *and preserve the order of the retained lines* with:

```
grep -v -x -f output_file input_file > input_file.bak && mv input_file.bak input_file
```

If the lines in the input are not unique, you can preserve the order of the retained lines with a bit more work:

```
sort -R input_file > shuffled
head -n $N shuffled > output_file
tail -n +$((N+1)) shuffled > keep
grep -x -f keep input_file > input_file.bak && mv input_file.bak input_file
```