# R extract percentage of entries out of textfile using readlines

Tags: r, text-files, readlines

Hi I have a very large txt-file (character) where I want to extract 10% of the entries and save those to another txt-file.

```
con1 <- file("ABC.txt", "rb")   # 2,36 mio DS
dfc1<-readLines(con1, ??? ,skipNul = TRUE)#
```

Instead of ??? I want to have something like <10% of all data> .

So If my ABC.txt was like

*" BBC Worldwide is a principle commercial arm and a wholly owned subsidiary of the British Broadcasting Corporation (BBC). The business exists to support the BBC public service mission and to maximise profits on its behalf..."*

my new file should contain only 10% (random) of the words like:

*" Worldwide business behalf..."*

**Is there a way to do that in R ?**

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing and extracting a random sample from a large .CSV in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981460/importing-and-extracting-a-random-sample-from-a-large-csv-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read in the text file, you can then use the stringr package to get a 10% random sample of the words using the following code:

```
text<- c("BBC Worldwide is a principle commercial arm and a wholly owned subsidiary of the British Broadcasting Corporation (BBC). The business exists to support the BBC public service mission and to maximise profits on its behalf...")
set.seed(9999)
library(stringr)
selection<-sample.int(str_count(text," ")+1, round(0.1*str_count(text," ")+1))
subset<-word(text, selection)
```